# Why AWS Neptune produce so many results for graph?

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune, gremlin-server

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATII4.png)

```
%%gremlin -p v,outE,inV,outE,inV,outE,inV,outE,inV,outE,inV,outE,inV,outE,inV,outE,inV,outE,inV -l 40 -le 40 -g Datagroup 

g.V().hasLabel('I-GPM').outE().inV().outE().inV().outE().inV().outE().inV().outE().inV().outE().inV().outE().inV().outE().inV().outE().inV().path().
by(valueMap().with(WithOptions.tokens)).by(label).limit(100000)
```

Why producing a graph like this generate  #100000 results?
Is there a way to optimize this while still producing the same graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that the [graph-notebook](https://github.com/aws/graph-notebook) decides what to display in terms of a visual rendering is based on any results that represent a `path`. So if the query yields 100,000 paths, it will try to render each of them visually. You can simplify your query hints however. You can remove the `-p` line if you change the query to use `path().by(elementMap())`.

Comment: Is there a way to know why I am producing so many paths for such a graph? I have multiple properties for each vertex, could this be the reason? Also, I did not import the data as a CSV file into Neptune instead I added them via a code format



addV("Retained_Customer").
    property(id,"PAGE_k3").
    property("Datagroup","KPI").
    property("Description","xx").
    property("Team","AC").
    property("Chart_Name","Customer_retention").
    property("Frequency","Monthly").
    property("Filter_Name","By Dealer Group / By Area Manager / By Region /By Dealer").
    as("PAGE_k3").

Comment: Your query as written is going to return all of the possible paths up to a limit of 100,000 including any that include cycles. If you have cycles in your graph, and you don't want them in the results, adding a `simplePath` step to the query should help. A cycle is a case such as `A->B->C->A`